# Remove duplicate's from Spark RDD

Tags: python, apache-spark, duplicates, pyspark

I have duplicated records in my file collected as a list of dictionaries. Here is my `sampleRDD` variable content, which is a `pyspark.rdd.RDD` object:

```
[{"A": 111, "B": 222, "C": 333}
,{"A": 111, "B": 222, "C": 333}]
```

I would like to get only one record as following:

```
[{"A": 111, "B": 222, "C": 333}]
```

Comment: Try the `distinct` method of `RDD`

Comment: I believe, given that elements within my list being dictionary - distinct method returns the following error : in mergeValues
    d[k] = comb(d[k], v) if k in d else creator(v)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'

Comment: To add more context {"A": 111, "B": 222, "C": 333} comes from a JSON file, just that in this case comes twice :(

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem doing Pyspark distinct on a list of dictionaries.
This is a way around it:

```
temp = sc.parallelize([{"A": 111, "B": 222, "C": 333}
,{"A": 111, "B": 222, "C": 333}])

print temp.map(lambda x: tuple(x.iteritems())).distinct().collect()
    >>[(('A', 111), ('C', 333), ('B', 222))]
```

Or if you need it back in dictionary form:

```
print temp.map(lambda x: tuple(x.iteritems())).distinct().map(lambda x: dict(x)).collect()
    >>[{'A': 111, 'C': 333, 'B': 222}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution, not sure if its efficient though ;)

Define function to remove duplicates:

```
def remove_repeat(dupRDD):
    return([dict(tup) for tup in set(tuple(item.items()) for item in dupRDD)])

# Assuming 'AAA' is main key (can pick any)
sampleRDD_2 = sampleRDD.map(lambda snap: (snap['AAA'], snap)).groupByKey()
```

this creates a RDD as `[(111, <pyspark.resultiterable.ResultIterable object>)]`

The pyspark object values can be fetched by list, passed to `remove_repeat` function

```
sampleRDD_2.map(lambda x : (x, remove_repeat(list(x[1])))).collect()
```

Returns deduped list of dict at the key level: `[(111,[{"A": 111, "B": 222, "C": 333}])]`